# ESLint un-used variables rule for parameters of function type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I'm using ESLint with TypeScript. When I try to create a function type with some required parameters, ESLint shows error `eslint: no-unused-vars`.

`type Func = (paramA: number) => void` Here, paramA is un-used variable according to ESLint.

My `.eslintrc.json` file

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

So, what is then, the correct way to create a function type in TypeScript with ESLint?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in the document of [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md), disabled the rule from eslint and enable from typescript-eslint.

```
{
  // note you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
  "no-unused-vars": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, they have answered to this question in their [FAQ](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/FAQ.md)

I needed to turn off eslint's, `no-unused-vars` rule, and turn on the `typescript-eslint` rule.

```
"rules": {
  "no-unused-vars": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you're trying to do is

```
const func: (paramA: number) => void
```

to define a function type.

Comment: You defined type to the constant named "func", but in my case, I did reusable type (type alias). In any way, ESLint still gives me the same error.